# why is setTimeout activating my animation ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hey guys have a look at this fiddle :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vb9jhq9/).

now what i am doing in this fiddle is when i click on any li element , i have a data attribute attached to each li element , and the Jquery code basically grabs the perticular li elements data value and displays it in a div , now i'd really like to combine CSS-3 and Jquery togeather .

with CSS-3 , every time i click on a li , it should have a small animation , I.E the below animation should be activated :

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform:rotateX(50deg) translateY(-20px);
        /*transform: translateX(100px);*/
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotateX(0deg) translateX(0px);
    }
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -o-animation-name: rotate;
    animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

I.E the animation should be activated before the li data can be displayed .

now my Jquery code is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {
                    $this = $(this);
                    var _stor = $this.data('says');
                    $('.testimo').removeClass('animated').html(_stor).addClass('animated');
                });
            });
```

now , i got my problem solved by asking one of my senior colleagues , he just said to use the setTimeOut function and so i changed my Jquery code to something as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {
        $this = $(this);
        var _stor = $this.data('says');
        $('.testimo').removeClass('animated');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.testimo') .html(_stor).addClass('animated');
        },100)
    });
});
```

Thsi works perfectly the way i want it to . but my question is WHY does this code work ? what is setTimeout have to do with an animation anyway ? my question is why does the code with setTimeout work ?

Heres the fiddle with [setTimeout](http://jsfiddle.net/5vb9jhq9/3/).

Thank you.

Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to get what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/5vb9jhq9/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {
        $this = $(this);
        var _stor = $this.data('says');
        $('.testimo').removeClass('animated').
            html(_stor).width($('.testimo').width).
            addClass('animated');
    });
});
```

As you can see this solution works fine too but, why?

The browser looks like it doesn't need to update screen or document until it needs really do it after executing whole function. So you can trigger an update in browser, for example, changing size (width, height, ect).

I don't know exactly why (maybe is a internal behavior of the browser) but it works without using a timer.

Best regards.